# Does it harm to switch off cpu power management (avoid idle sates) in BIOS permanently?

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, power-management, idle

I discovered a problem with lost usb packets from an external usb camera and thanks to you guys found out that the reason is idle states of the CPUs, resp. packages ([Monitor used USB bandwidth in Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/1648849/monitor-used-usb-bandwidth-in-win10/1649080#1649080)).

Thus I switched off CPU power management in the BIOS, which worked like a charm and over hours the camera was running fine without loosing data.

So my question now is: Does it damage the computer on the long run to permanently avoid idle states (disabling CPU power management in BIOS)? Will the comuter or CPU chipset break sooner because something is running now permanently with full power?

Comment: Anecdotally, I have several Xeons that don't have any power management at all that have been running 24/7/365 [never sleep, never shut down other than for cleaning] for 13 years & still doing fine.

Comment: Potentially a dupe, but basically an edge case: https://superuser.com/questions/1272711/how-long-will-a-cpu-last-running-24-7

Comment: If the temperature does not increase significantly, and the PC operates normally, there's no reason for concern. IC's, other than flash RAM, don't generally "wear out". What eventually may destroy an IC is heat, voltage spike, or even cosmic rays. BTW, space vehicles have wide architecture IC's, which are  more robust, and redundant circuits to keep functioning after a particle destroys one.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik: Yes, I had once the chance to see some boards meant to go on a space mission. Looks like back to the 80s, so big and robust... Thanks for your estimation on ICs!